# Setting string values as xaxis labels of an MPAndroidChart bar graph

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to format the labels of by bar chart from float to strings but It is only showing one label as shown here
[image: chart with one label showing]
without the formatter this is what I have
[image: Chart showing labels without formatter]
here it the formatter inner class code

```
    private static class MyFormatter extends ValueFormatter {
      public String getAxisLabel(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        if (value == 1) {
            return "JAN"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (value == 2) {
            return "FEB"; //make it a string and return
        } else if (value == 3) {
            return "MAR"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (value == 4) {
            return "APR"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (value == 5) {
            return "MAY"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (value == 6) {
            return "JUN"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (value == 7) {
            return "JUL"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (value == 8) {
            return "AUG"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (value == 9) {
            return "SEP"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (value == 10) {
            return "OCT"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (value == 11) {
            return "NOV"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (value == 12) {
            return "DEC"; //make it a string and return
        } else {
            return ""; // return empty for other values where you don't want to print anything on the X Axis
        }
    }
}
```

here is how I am adding the values to the dataset and eventually formatting the labels

```
    if (response.body() != null) {
                List<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
                for (MonthlySales monthlySales : response.body()) {
                    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(monthlySales.getMonth(), monthlySales.getTotal()));
                }
                BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Monthly Sales");
                dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
                BarData data = new BarData(dataSet);
                //data.setBarWidth(10f);
                chart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
                chart.setData(data);
                chart.setFitBars(true);
                Description description = new Description();
                description.setText("Sales per month");
                chart.setDescription(description);
                chart.invalidate();
                XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
                //xAxis.setLabelCount(12, true);
                xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
                //xAxis.setTypeface();
                xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
                //xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyFormatter());
            }
```

note that the returned months from the database is an integer 1-12 but it is showing the floats of the four months may - august.

What could I be doing wrong and how can I achieve my target with this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is convert your floating point values to integer using Math.round() this will ensure that the checks evaluate to true accurately since as at now they are only evaluating to true at 7.0 since that is equal to 7 while the rest are evaluating to false even when it should be true
your formatting code should thus be

```
private static class MyFormatter extends ValueFormatter {
    public String getAxisLabel(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        if (Math.round(value) == 1) {
            return "JAN"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (Math.round(value) == 2) {
            return "FEB"; //make it a string and return
        } else if (Math.round(value) == 3) {
            return "MAR"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (Math.round(value) == 4) {
            return "APR"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (Math.round(value) == 5) {
            return "MAY"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (Math.round(value) == 6) {
            return "JUN"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (Math.round(value) == 7) {
            return "JUL"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (Math.round(value) == 8) {
            return "AUG"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (Math.round(value) == 9) {
            return "SEP"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (Math.round(value) == 10) {
            return "OCT"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (Math.round(value) == 11) {
            return "NOV"; //make it a string and return
        } else  if (Math.round(value) == 12) {
            return "DEC"; //make it a string and return
        } else {
            return ""; // return empty for other values where you don't want to print anything on the X Axis
        }
    }
}
```

Also remember to add the granularity feature to your x axis so that only one label is shown when the charts are zoomed for large screens.

to use granularity feature add this to your chart creation code

```
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
```